# Watcher on class change jquery sdk

Tags: javascript, jquery, sdk

I created an sdk that works on images, now I would like to manage the images inside a slider.
For this I need to fire an event when the images class changes.
Anyone know what is the solution? I can't find any feasible solution for handle this event.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#images').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
      alert('do something when class changes');
      let hasClass = $(this).hasClass('the_class_u_are_listening_for');
      if(hasClass) {
        //do something
      }
  });
});
```